# How do I print a list of lists where the inner lists contain both strings and lists of strings?

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, flatten

For example,

```
list1 = [ ['str1', 'str2', 'str3'],
          [['str4', 'str5'], 'str6', 'str7', 'str8'],
          ['str9', 'str10']]
```

I would like list1 to output as follows:

```
str1 str2 str3
str4 str5 str6 str7 str8
str9 str10
```

This way each of the inner lists belonging to the first layer of inner lists are on their own lines.

In the above example I would call the section depicted below an inner list of the first layer:

```
['str1', 'str2', 'str3']
```

However in the following section I would say str4 and str5 are in an inner list belonging to the second layer. In other words they belong to an inner list of an inner list.

```
[['str4', 'str5'], 'str6', 'str7', 'str8']
```

Comment: What's the logic of your line breaks? Why are there line breaks after `str3`, `str8` and `str10` but not `str5`?

Comment: I want to print each of the inner lists on a separate line.

Comment: Also, you appear to be missing a comma after `'str8']`.

Comment: I added the comma, thanks.

Comment: So you should edit your expected output so that `str4 str5` are on a separate line from `str6 str7 str8`.

Comment: This is a little tedious to word... I ran into a situation similar to the above situation from recursively tokenizing some strings. What I want is for each of the first inner lists to be printed on separate lines. However if the first inner lists contain more lists I would like to count them as part of the same line.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what the rule for linebreaks is, instead of making us try to figure it out from comment replies.

Comment: Thanks, I made some edits. Please let me know if there is any other way to elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.chain` for this:

```
list1 = [['str1', 'str2', 'str3'],
        [['str4', 'str5'], 'str6', 'str7', 'str8'],
        ['str9', 'str10']]

from itertools import chain

def listy(x):
    return x if isinstance(x, list) else [x]

for sublist in list1:
    print(' '.join(chain.from_iterable(map(listy, sublist))))

str1 str2 str3
str4 str5 str6 str7 str8
str9 str10
```

Comment: Hey jpp, could you include a little info on the time complexity of the itertools library function you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive function to deal with any depth of sub-lists, but make the printing of newline characters after each sub-list optional and only enable it at the first call.

```
list1 = [ ['str1', 'str2', 'str3'],
        [['str4', 'str5'], 'str6', 'str7', 'str8'],
        ['str9', 'str10']]
def p(l, newline=True):
    output = ''
    for i in l:
        if isinstance(i, str):
            output += i + ' '
        else:
            p(i, False)
            if newline:
                print()
    print(output, end='')
p(list1)
```

This outputs:

```
str1 str2 str3 
str4 str5 str6 str7 str8 
str9 str10
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to loop through the first inner layer then flatten the  elements inside it.

Then print it in order with join function. Detail below.

```
list1 = [ ['str1', 'str2', 'str3'],
        [['str4', 'str5'], 'str6', 'str7', 'str8'],
        ['str9', 'str10']]

def flatten(lst):
    if lst==[]:
        return lst
    else:
        if isinstance(list[0], list):
            return flatten(lst[0])+flatten(lst[1:])
        else:
            return [lst[0],]+flatten(lst[1:])

def print_it(lst_rino):
    for lst in lst_rino:
        new_lst=flatten(lst)
        print(" ".join(new_lst))

print_it(list1)

The Output:

str1 str2 str3
str4 str5 str6 str7 str8
str9 str10
```

Comment: I think `isinstance(list[0], list)` is cleaner than `type(lst[0])==list`.

Answer (score 0):

Still new to python but cant this be solved with simple string concatenation and list elements?

something along the lines of

```
list1 = [['str1', 'str2', 'str3'],[['str4', 'str5'], 'str6', 'str7', 'str8'],['str9', 'str10']]

print(str(list1[0]) + '\n' + str(list1[1]) + '\n' + str(list1[2]))
```

output is exactly what op asked for?

```
['str1', 'str2', 'str3']
[['str4', 'str5'], 'str6', 'str7', 'str8']
['str9', 'str10']
```

Comment: The OP asked for a print sequences. So the ouput should be printed like he/she asker for not a string representation like what you did.

Comment: eh i tried, Still have a long way to go before I should be answering questions i guess XD